# Paypal payment destroys Session on "Return"

Tags: php, session, paypal, session-variables, session-cookies

This question has been asked before.  But, I am still unable to find a solution.

I have integrated Paypal Payment into my website.  I created and installed the "Payment Button"  (the HTML code), and it works perfectly.

The problem, however, is that : after being re-directed to Paypal to make the payment, the user's session on my website is destroyed. Meaning : after payment is successful (or canceled by the user, whichever).......the "Return URL" does not work, because the user has been logged out.

I did contact paypal, of course; and, as I expected, they were next to useless (exactly as many people here have already attested to).

As I said earlier, this question has been asked before, here :

[Anybody ever used PayPal Website Payments Standard with SESSION variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208283/anybody-ever-used-paypal-website-payments-standard-with-session-variables)

The answer proposed by "Woppi" in that thread seemed ok. But, when I tried it, it did not work.  (of course, that thread is 3 years old).

I really don't know what else to do.

I should point out the following, however (this makes no difference, but I want to be as clear as possible) :

(a) On my website's "Log-Out Page", I have set all sessions to be destroyed :

```
     session_unset();

     unset($_SESSION['login']);
     unset($_SESSION['password']);

     session_destroy();

     session_write_close();
```

As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with this code. It completely wipes out and destroys any and all sessions (which should be the case, shouldn't it?  Otherwise, what is the point of logging out? )

(b)  I do not have "Cookies" set anywhere  (which may be part of the problem, although I am not sure). However, I do have these in my HTML header :

```
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0">
```

(c)  In the old thread (given above), it requires the value : $session_id;

At the beginning of every PHP page in my website, I have the :

```
   **<?php session_start();**
```

This has worked so far for me; I did not assign any specific ID anywhere else.

**UPDATE**

I am now using cookies in my PHP to try to resolve this problem;

At the top of the PHP payment form, I have this :

```
  <?php session_start();

  if (!(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {

  header ("Location: /example/access_denied");

  exit() ;
  }     

  $cookie_name = "user_paying";
  $cookie_value = $_SESSION['login'];
  $date_of_expiry = time() + 600 ;

  setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $date_of_expiry, '/', FALSE,TRUE);
```

(I set cookies to expire after 10 minutes);

Then, in my "Return-Form"  (where the user is re-directed after making payment in Paypal),  I have this at the top :

```
 <?php session_start();

 if (!isset($_COOKIE['user_paying'])) {
 setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $date_of_expiry, '/', FALSE,TRUE); 
 }

 else {

 // etc, etc, etc..........code continues
```

Comment: I don't use PHP so I cannot direct you to code in that language to illustrate how to handle sesison, but I can tell you that a) PayPal does NOT destroy your session, and in fact cannot destroy it if you use a cookie, and b) you should probably be using a cookie-based session, as is recommended in the accepted answer to the question you referenced. If you want to use the more fragile cookie-less in-page-only session (which would only live page to page, so anyone leaving your site would loose their session) you can use pass-through variables as described in the 2nd answer but its more complex.

Comment: As above, Paypal cannot "destroy cookies". Also not a Php dev, so the generic (doesn't matter what platform) suggestion would be to check your `cookie` scope (domain, protocol, etc.), and session handling - at the end of the day, "sessions" _are_ cookies on the client-side (unless of course you use some other means of maintaining state).