# Validate whether payment was a success or failure

Tags: session, button, status

I am looking to use PayPal to accept a payment through my website. I am looking at the Smart Payment button option. If the payment is successful I need to update something in my website DB. How can I determine whether the payment was successful or not? I cant see anything the API docs.

I also need to retain user context with a PHP session ID. How can I pass that to the paypal site and ensure it is returned with the success / fail indicator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Braintree API for this use case. Ther Brantree API returns a unique payment identifier (payment Nonce) which you can then validate by submitting a call back to the Braintree API to ensure the payment was actually received properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Paypal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) to receive payment notifications. Setup a server endpoint to respond to IPN requests and update your DB etc...

To maintain state, you will need to include a hidden input filed in your Smart Payment Button with a name of `custom` and a value of your choice (session id).

Setup a IPN endpoint ie: /checkout/ipn, to receive Paypal notifications. Capture the session ID with $_POST['custom'];

Comment: Thanks Scriptonomy. IPN might be a useful option. I am still not clear how I send say a customer ID with the payment and then pick up that same customer ID from IPN. Similarly I am not sure how the hidden input field posted to the payment page would be returned with the payment result. (This aspect of PayPal documentation is not great in my opinion). I might abandon the simple PayPal button approach in favour of the Braintree API. It returns a payment Nonce with the client side javascript which I can then validate from the PayPal server with my server side code once a payment is successful.

Comment: In terms of losing the user session, I can see that other users are having trouble with that too. Because the PayPal button takes you to a completely new URL it is easy to lose session context. This is why i think a combo of client side js and server side code (via Braintree API) is best. Otherwise you have to resort to cookies like in this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069675/paypal-payment-destroys-session-on-return?rq=1